# Image not showing in head section {HTML/CSS}

Tags: html, css, image, header

I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS. I want to design a page with some images, logos and icons. I want to add my logo and social media links with icons in my header section. But my HTML/CSS code don't show the images. I already taken images in solid folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TahmidPro</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="home.png" type="image/png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .head {
      padding: 40px;
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/cvr.jpg" alt="LOGO"></div>


    <div class="social"></div>

    <h1>Its Header</h1>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

What can I do?

Comment: try dragging an image into the tag, if your editor supports drag n drop, probably the path is incorrect

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't support! Another way plz?

Comment: Check the file path to be sure. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Tweaked formatting

Comment: is the images folder under your current folder try this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 0):

Place your image(cvr.jpg) next to index file if you  are using hosting site and use

```
<img src=cvr.jpg>
```